# Using CSS or JS to auto-expand submenus on mobile site

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, drop-down-menu, menu

I am looking to have my mobile site's menu automatically expand the top menu item's submenu after the hamburger menu is tapped. I have tried using this CSS, but it doesn't work:

```
 .menu-item-has-children {
display: block !important;
}
```

I noticed that when the top menu item has its submenu opened, an attribute called `aria-expanded` toggles from `false` to `true`.

Is there any way to default that attribute to `true` without using JS? If not, any JS suggestions would be much appreciated.

[Here is a link to the one page on my staging site with this menu applied](https://smddrake1.wpengine.com/about-us/)

[This is what the mobile menu looks like currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ0MG.png)

[This is what I'm trying to get it to look like (submenu expanded)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htfdc.png)

Comment: Can you provide a runnable demo or a list a picture or two of what your problem is?

Comment: @ControlAltDel Yes, just updated the post with screenshots.